# How do I define a object parameter in a constructor

Tags: java, object, constructor

```
Public class BookListing extends Book{

    private double price;
    
    public BookListing( Book b, double p)
    {
        Book = b; //What would I set Book b to since it is an object. 
        price = p; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you pass a Book instance to a class that itself is a Book? What's the point? It looks like you don't actually want to use `extends Book`, but instead have a property to save the passed Book object. You already did something similar with `price`, so you know what you need to know to save the Book instance as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a private variable of type Book. I used also `this` to avoid any confusions to what I'm assigning but it is not mandatory.

I have to say that it probably doesn't make sense that a BookListing extends a Book, from a conceptual point of view. The BookListing contains a Book already with the variable I added. I'm removing the `extends` clause for my answer. Feel free to add it back if you need it.

```
Public class BookListing {

    private double price;
    private Book book;
    
    public BookListing (Book b, double p) {
        this.book = b;
        this.price = p; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to remove the BookListing extends Book as I realized it was wrong. You answered my question though thank you